# Persisted Navigation Term Set Synchronization job failure

Tags: 2016, timer-jobs, managed-navigation

I can see in Event Viewer a standard job failure event 6398 when Persisted Navigation Term Set Synchronization tries to execute.

More information:

> There are no addresses available for this application

Additional ULS information:

> ContentDatabaseJob Failure:
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEndpointAddressNotFoundException: There are no
>   addresses available for this application.      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoundRobinServiceLoadBalancer.BeginOperation() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy.<>c__DisplayClass4d.b__49()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy.RunOnChannel(CodeToRun
>   codeToRun, String operationName, Double operationTimeoutFactor)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Internal.TaxonomyProxyAccess.GetChangedTermSets(DateTime
>   sinceTime, String propertyName, String propertyValue)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Internal.DataAccessManager.GetChangedTermSets(DateTime
>   sinceTime, String propertyName, String propertyValue)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.PersistedNavigationTermSetSyncJobDefinition.GetChangedTermSetsFromAllPartitions(MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy
>   proxy, DateTime lastUpdate)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.PersistedNavigationTermSetSyncJobDefinition.UpdateLocalTermSets(MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy
>   proxy, SPContentDatabase contentDatabase, DateTime lastUpdate)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.PersistedNavigationTermSetSyncJobDefinition.Execute(SPContentDatabase
>   contentDatabase, SPJobState jobState)

What could be the cause for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the fix for the problem was really simple. Managed Metadata Web Service wasn't started.

Fix:

1. Central Administration > System Settings > Manage services on server > Managed Metadata Web Service > Start
2. IISRESET
3. Restart SharePoint Timer Service